# Snowflake Query Profile Interface

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Have been played around with the Snowflake Query Profile Interface but missing information about the parallelism in query execution. Using a Large or XLarge Warehouse it is still only using two servers to execute the query. Having an XLarge Warehouse a big sort could be divided in 16 parallel execution threads to fully exploit my Warehouse and credits. Or?

Example: Having a Medium Warehouse as:

[Medium Warehouse => 4 servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PPGS.png)

Executing the following query:

select
sum(o_totalprice) "order total",
count(*) "number of orders",
c.c_name "customer"
from
orders o inner join customer c on c.c_custkey = o.o_custkey
where
c.c_nationkey in (2,7,22)
group by
c.c_name

Gives the following Query Plan:

[Query Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4x5Ck.png)

In the execution details I cannot see anything about the participating servers:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB0wA.png)

Best Regards
Jan Isaksson

Comment: Jan, thanks for sharing the additional details. Are you looking for getting information on the underlying clusters? If that is the case, you will not get that details. Maximum you can see if you have a multi-cluster warehouse, which clusters were used. Snowflake is a SaaS and hence does not expose the internal working of the virtual warehouse. To see which cluster is being used look at CLUSTER_NUMBER in the QUERY_HISTORY view.

Comment: Ok! It would have been interesting to see the degree of parallelism within the cluster depending on the nature of the SQL query. Thanks anyway Rajib for your support //Jan

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal situation snowflake will try to split your query and let every core of the warehouse to process a piece of the query. For example, if you have a 2XL warehouse, you have 32x8 = 256 cores(each node in a warehouse has 8 cores). So, if a query is submitted, in an ideal situation snowflake will try to divide it into 256 parts and have each core process a part.

In reality, it may not be possible to parallize to that extent and that is because either the query itself cannot be broken down like that(for example, if you are trying to calculate let's say a median) or if the data itself is preventing it to parallelize(for example if you are trying to run a window function on a column which is skewed) it to that extent.

Hence, it is not always true that if you move to a bigger warehouse your query performance will improve linearly.

Comment: Thanks Rajib for answering my issue. I understand that this would be the intention with the number of nodes and what you state also cores in my cluster. But I have hard to even get two nodes working on my query, at least what the profiler display on the console.

Comment: Will it be possible to share your query and a snapshot of the query profile view. Please also go to the warehouse tab and send a snapshot of that. I wanted to see if you are using a multi-cluster warehouse or a regular one

Answer (score 0):

I tested your query starting with smallest compute size and the up.  The linear scaling (more compute resource results in improved performance) stops around medium size, at which point there is no added benefit of performance improvement.  This indicates your query is not big enough to take advantage of more compute resource and size s is good enough, especially considering cost optimization.

Comment: Yes, but it would have been nice to see an indication in the query tree the number of servers used in the cluster. Cheers //Jan